# How to make a complex MongoDB query with multiple inputs

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection set of objects with 4 ids on them, something like:

```
{ 
    location_id : ObjectId,
    project_id : ObjectId,
    department_id : ObjectId,
    element_id : ObjectId
}
```

My user can send me an array of objects with that same shape, called "candidates", and I have to return all the records I have where the properties match or where they are null in the database.

If they only could pass one candidate object, the query would like this:

```
{ 
        location_id : { $in : [null, candidate.location_id)] }, 
        project_id : { $in : [null, candidate.project_id)] }, 
        department_id : { $in : [null, candidate.department_id)] }, 
        element_id : { $in : [null, candidate.element_id)] }    
}
```

This works.   What I need to know is...how do I run this same query with multiple input candidates at once?

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of additional logic should do the trick.

Let's say you have an array of candidates sent from the user to use as filter like this:

```
const filters = [
  {
    location_id: 'someId',
    project_id: 'someId',
    department_id: 'someId',
    element_id: 'someId'
  },
  {
    location_id: 'someId',
    project_id: 'someId',
  },
  {
    location_id: 'someId',
    project_id: 'someId',
    department_id: 'someId',
    element_id: 'someId'
  }
];
```

You can write a simple logic to convert this filter array into something you can pass to MongoDB:

```
const locationMatch = [null];
const projectMatch = [null];
const departmentMatch = [null];
const elementMatch = [null];

filters.forEach(filter => {
  const { location_id, department_id, project_id, element_id } = filter;
  if(location_id) locationMatch.push(location_id);
  if(project_id) projectMatch.push(project_id);
  if(department_id) departmentMatch.push(department_id);
  if(element_id) elementMatch.push(element_id);
})
```

Your MongoDB query would then be like this:

```
db.candidates.find({
  location_id: {
    $in: locationMatch,
  },
  project_id: {
    $in: projectMatch,
  },
  department_id: {
    $in: departmentMatch,
  },
  element_id: {
    $in: elementMatch,
  },
})
```